# Pepper robot emulator does not have access to internet

Tags: android, firebase, android-emulator, pepper

Recently, I had tried to make an application for pepper robot which uses firebase services. The application works well in the real robot but does not work on the emulator tablet from the Softbank.
I am using macOS during development. Has anybody encountered this issue?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what exactly doesn't work? I am also using pepper with Android studio and I can successfully make API requests to dialog flow. ( I am a windows user) 
Also, there is a recent update on the emulator so please check with that.

Comment: try to check onRobotFocusGained()  is called or not? I believe in emulator it will not called. If you initialized Firebase services inside the onRobotFocusGained() will cause the error.

Comment: I can make an API request in the real robot. But I cannot make in the android emulator (from Softbank )which is connected with the simulator robot.

Comment: Some of the firebase services such as firebase auth require to have a google play service but I cannot install play service in the android emulator of the pepper.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Actually, I have to use the firebase SDKs which does not require google play services. As in the android emulator from Softbank does not has google play service installed on it but it does have internet access in the android emulator.